# SASS SCSS - Problemas com arredondamento.

Tags: css, sass, grid, less

Estou com o seguinte problema: desenvolvendo um sistema de Grid com SCSS, obtive o problema de arredondamento das porcentagens que definem o tamanho de cada coluna.
Queria saber se alguém tem a solução para arredondamento de variáveis, pois quebra todo o esquema.

Valeu,

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa encontrada, na linha de comando existe a possibilidade de usar o atributo de "--precision" o qual usei 100 casas após a virgula:
No terminal:

```
scss --watch --precision 100 grid.scss:grid.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira é usar a função "round" do SCSS. Ela arredonda um número para o inteiro mais próximo. Por exemplo, se você tiver uma variável $width com o valor 0,66666 e quiser arredondá-la para 2 casas decimais, você pode usar a seguinte sintaxe: $width: round($width, 2);

Outra maneira é usar a função "percentage" do SCSS, que força um número a ser tratado como uma porcentagem. Por exemplo, se você tem uma variável $width com o valor 0,66666 e quer forçá-la a ser tratada como 66,67%, você pode usar a seguinte sintaxe: $width: percentage($width);

Outra opção é usar a função "floor" ou "ceil" do SCSS, que arredondam para baixo ou para cima respectivamente.

Eu recomendo testar cada uma das funções e ver qual se adapta melhor à sua necessidade de arredondamento.